# Threading and asynchronous operations in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm an old dog trying to learn a new trick. I'm extremely familiar with a language called PowerBuilder and in that language, when you want to do things asynchronously, you spawn an object in a new thread. I'll reiterate that: *the entire object is instantiated in a separate thread and has a different execution context*. Any and all methods on that object execute in the context of that separate thread.

Well now, I'm trying to implement some asynchronous executing using C# and the threading model in .NET feels completely different to me. It looks like I'm instantiating objects in one thread but that I can specify (on a call-by-call basis) that certain methods execute in a different thread.

The difference seems subtle, but it's frustrating me. My old-school thinking says, "I have a helper named Bob. Bob goes off and does stuff." The new-school thinking, if I understand it right, is "I *am* Bob. If I need to, I can sometimes rub my belly and pat my head *at the same time*."

My real-world coding problem: I'm writing an interface engine that accepts messages via TCP, parses them into usable data, then puts that data into a database. "Parsing" a message takes approximately one second. Depending on the parsed data, the database operation may take less than a second or it might take ten seconds. (All times made up to clarify the problem.)

My old-school thinking tells me that my database class should live in a separate thread and have something like a [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It would simply spin on that queue, processing anything that might be in there. The Parser, on the other hand, would need to push messages into that queue. These messages would be (delegates?) things like "Create an order based on the data in `this object`" or "Update an order based on the data in `this object`". It might be worth noting that I actually want to process the "messages" in the "queue" in a strict, single-threaded FIFO order.

Basically, my database connection can't always keep up with my parser. I need a way to make sure my parser doesn't slow down while my database processes try to catch up. Advice?

-- edit: with code!
Everyone and everything is telling me to use `BlockingCollection`. So here's a *brief* explanation of the end goal and code to go with it:

This will be a Windows service. When started, it will spawn multiple "environments", with each "environment" containing one "dbworker" and one "interface". The "interface" will have one "parser" and one "listener".

```
class cEnvironment {
    private cDBWorker MyDatabase;
    private cInterface MyInterface;

    public void OnStart () {
        MyDatabase = new cDBWorker ();
        MyInterface = new cInterface ();

        MyInterface.OrderReceived += this.InterfaceOrderReceivedEventHandler;

        MyDatabase.OnStart ();
        MyInterface.OnStart ();
    }

    public void OnStop () {
        MyInterface.OnStop ();
        MyDatabase.OnStop ();

        MyInterface.OrderReceived -= this.InterfaceOrderReceivedEventHandler;
    }

    void InterfaceOrderReceivedEventHandler (object sender, OrderReceivedEventArgs e) {
        MyDatabase.OrderQueue.Add (e.Order);
    }
}

class cDBWorker {
    public BlockingCollection<cOrder> OrderQueue = new BlockingCollection<cOrder> ();
    private Task ProcessingTask;

    public void OnStart () {
        ProcessingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Process (), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void OnStop () {
        OrderQueue.CompleteAdding ();
        ProcessingTask.Wait ();
    }

    public void Process () {
        foreach (cOrder Order in OrderQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable ()) {
            switch (Order.OrderType) {
                case 1:
                    SuperFastMethod (Order);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ReallySlowMethod (Order);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void SuperFastMethod (cOrder Order) {
    }

    public void ReallySlowMethod (cOrder Order) {
    }
}

class cInterface {
    protected cListener MyListener;
    protected cParser MyParser;

    public void OnStart () {
        MyListener = new cListener ();
        MyParser = new cParser ();

        MyListener.DataReceived += this.ListenerDataReceivedHandler;
        MyListener.OnStart ();
    }

    public void OnStop () {
        MyListener.OnStop ();
        MyListener.DataReceived -= this.ListenerDataReceivedHandler;
    }

    public event OrderReceivedEventHandler OrderReceived;

    protected virtual void OnOrderReceived (OrderReceivedEventArgs e) {
        if (OrderReceived != null)
            OrderReceived (this, e);
    }

    void ListenerDataReceivedHandler (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        foreach (string Message in MyParser.GetMessages (e.RawData)) {
            OnOrderReceived (new OrderReceivedEventArgs (MyParser.ParseMessage (Message)));
        }
    }
```

It compiles. (SHIP IT!) But does that mean that I'm doing it right?

Comment: So, have you tried implementing that?  It sounds like you at least know where to start.  On a side note, a `BlockingCollection` may be more suitable than an explicit concurrent queue (it will use one internally).

Comment: Also note that threads will virtually always share the same memory space.  Threads, at the lowest level, don't "own" an object, but programmers often (and justifiably) apply their own constraints that a given object be only used in a single thread, which makes it easier to reason about said object.  While you *can* use a given object in multiple threads, it's often not a good idea to do so (with the exception of objects *built* to be used by multiple threads, like say a `BlockingCollection`), or data that is "read only".

Comment: For my understanding the Queue already separates the processing - on the one side you are filling it asynchronously and on the other side you are pulling it asynchronously. It seems safe - the two components don't block each other.

Comment: @pasty [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) most certainly is not safe to use from multiple threads, however [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me except that your queue items should probably be message objects, not delegates. Having objects that own threads is a pattern I use from time to time, just make sure you clean up after yourself in dispose and expose a thread safe interface.

Comment: [Yosi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2628137/yosi), there's no code because I don't know (yet) how to use any of these classes. I was asking if I was looking in the right direction. ([Servy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) and [Yaur](http://stackoverflow.com/users/184025/yaur) seem to think I'm on the right track.) I'll start playing with some code and update my question... probably tomorrow. Thanks, so far, to all!

Comment: The model of threading you are used to is called the Apartment Model; an object is associated with a thread and can only be used on that thread. This is a highly restricted model designed to simplify multithreaded programming; in particular, components that interact with the UI thread should be apartment threaded. It is a subset of the set of behaviours available in general, as you are discovering.

Comment: Your "Bob" analogy indicates your confusion. The right way to think about threading in C# is that threads are workers hired by the process and objects are their tools. Apartment threaded objects are tools that are owned by a specific worker and can only be used by that worker. Rental threaded objects are tools that can be used by one worker at a time, but handed from worker to worker. Free threaded objects can be used by many workers at once.

Comment: You might do better to approach threading in C# via the Task Parallel Library; in the TPL the fundamental unit is not the thread -- the worker -- but rather the task that the workers are assigned. The business of assigning workers to tasks is handled by the TPL on your behalf.

Comment: Also, don't mistake *asynchrony* for *concurrency*. An asynchronous operation is one that will give a result in the future. A concurrent operation is one that runs at the same time as another. If you require asynchrony you might not need concurrency. When you need to put off filing your taxes, you don't hire a secretary to sit there waiting for your tax documents to arrive. You simply choose to do other work, and when you take a break from it, check the mailbox. C# does not require multiple threads for asynchrony.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i used Queue as a "general topic word" (using queues approach to solve the problem), i don't meant the class Queue (i should have written the word with small q).

Comment: To your update with a possible solution, `TryTake` returns instantly with false if there is no work to be done. This will cause 100% CPU usage while the queue sits empty. Instead use [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will block while the collection is empty and not use CPU. It also handles the checking of `IsCompleted` for you so you can remove that check also. Here how I would do it `public void Process () { foreach( cOrder Order in OrderQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) { switch (Order.OrderType) { ...(no changes)... } } }`.

Comment: Also [your capitalization standard is wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), classes should be `PascalCasing`, local variables are `camelCasing`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, my concern with `GetConsumingEnumerable()` is specifically because it blocks. This program may get hundreds of orders in a single second, but it might also sit for five minutes with no orders at all and then suddenly get another hundred orders. I need to be able to gracefully stop the program at any time, which I fear a blocking operation might interfere with. If `GetConsumingEnumerable()` covers all of that, great! I just can't tell from the documentation if it will. You're definitely right, though, in that I need a way to spin in `Process()` that doesn't consume the CPU.

Comment: @Jason The question is how do you define "Gracefully", does that mean process the queue till it is empty but don't add new orders, or stop after the current order is done? If the latter then use [`GetConsumingEnumerable(CancelationToken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as that is the exact situation it was designed for. All you need to do is when you start the processor up call `OrderQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(myCancelationTokenSource.Token)` and then in `OnStop()` call `myCancelationTokenSource.Cancel()` to make it stop processing early.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! At first, I was planning on always making sure the queue was empty when the program is stopped, but I'm starting to think that a CancellationToken is the better solution. (The program is to run as a Windows service and the OS expects the service to stop in a timely manner.) But just to clarify: It **does** handle instances where the queue is empty but I'm not stopping the program, right? I don't want the program to consider itself complete simply because the queue is empty. It'll need to pick back up the next time something gets added to the queue.

Comment: I was about to suggest using [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) to schedule tasks on an STA thread and manage the workflow with `async/await`. That might be an overkill though. @EricLippert, would you consider putting your comments together as an answer - well worth up-voting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) makes putting this kind of thing together pretty easy:

```
// the queue
private BlockingCollection<Message> MessagesQueue = new BlockingCollection<Message>();


// the consumer
private MessageParser()
{
    foreach (var msg in MessagesQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        var parsedMessage = ParseMessage(msg);
        // do something with the parsed message
    }
}

// In your main program
// start the consumer
var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MessageParser(),
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// the main loop
while (messageAvailable)
{
    var msg = GetMessageFromTcp();
    // add it to the queue
    MessagesQueue.Add(msg);
}

// done receiving messages
// tell the consumer that no more messages will be added
MessagesQueue.CompleteAdding();

// wait for consumer to finish
consumer.Wait();
```

The consumer does a non-busy wait on the queue, so it's not eating CPU resources when there's nothing available.

Comment: Additional kudos to [Servy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy), [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), and [Scott Chamberlain](http://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain)! Original post edited with final code.