# this BlockingCollection is not FIFO as I expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, fifo, blockingcollection

thanks for looking at my question: I have a (non gui thread) `BlockingCollection` that I had always assumed would be FIFO (First in First Out) but I now realise it isn't

I have pasted an example of the code on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lOpGCf) but because it doesn't run multithreads you can't see the error happening, but you can see the code

ok. So what did I want? I wanted to make a second thread (non GUI) in `Visual Studio Express 2013 C# Winforms` that would be like a work house that would do the things it was passed in the order it was sent them.

I opted for a structure that is like this:

```
nofQDo
|_addAction(|)
            |
            +-> static BlockingCollection foreach
                                          |
                                          +-> QDo.run(|)
                                                      |
                                                      +> QDoType.action(//code//)
```

the reason for this strange arrangement was that I wanted to have up to 20 or 30 `types` of queue object (I call these all `QDoType_something`) and I am happy with the layout out but the engine doesn't work if I call

```
QDoType_test gra = new QDoType_test("hey0");
nofQDo.addAction(gra);

QDoType_test grb = new QDoType_test("hey1");
nofQDo.addAction(grb);

QDoType_test grc = new QDoType_test("hey2");
nofQDo.addAction(grc);

 QDoType_test grd = new QDoType_test("hey3");
 nofQDo.addAction(grd);

 QDoType_test gre = new QDoType_test("hey4");
 nofQDo.addAction(gre);

 QDoType_test grf = new QDoType_test("hey5");
 nofQDo.addAction(grf);
```

I get

```
00009::hey0
00009::hey1
00009::hey5
00009::hey3
00009::hey2
00009::hey4
```

or

```
00009::hey1
00009::hey0
00009::hey3
00009::hey2
00009::hey4
00009::hey5
```

so it clearly isn't "`FIFO`"  and this is alarming.. is there a way to ensure that my `BlockingCollection` is a) `not gui` thread b) only ever running as one extra thread and c) that this second thread is always running `FIFO` (First in First Out?)

as requested: Here is the code proper:

=QDoType_test.cs=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QTest
{
    class QDoType_test : QDoType
    {
        String szout = "";
        private string ThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString("00000");
        public QDoType_test(String sent)
        {
            szout = sent;
        }
        public override void action()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(ThreadId + "::" + szout);
        }
    }
}
```

=nofQDo.cs=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QTest
{
    class nofQDo
    {
        static BlockingCollection<QDo> queue = new BlockingCollection<QDo>(new ConcurrentQueue<QDo>()); //<--new ConcurrentQueue<QDo>() makes it FIFO

        public static void addAction(QDoType action)
        {
            QDo me = new QDo(action);
            queue.Add(me);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (QDo doThis in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    doThis.run();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

=QDoType.cs=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a Parent Class for QDoType_whatever they are non 
    /// communicative and most exist to run db calls
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class QDoType
    {
        /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\
         * this is a parent class not meant to ever be instaciated   *
        \* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

        public string uniqueid = "";
        public Action callback;

        public abstract void action();

        /// <summary>
        /// kept for the fact you might want 
        /// to debug where it went in the Queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uid"></param>
        public void setUniqueId(string uid)
        {
            uniqueid = uid;
        }
    }
}
```

=QDo.cs=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QTest
{
    class QDo
    {
        /***********
         * 
         * This class is the <T> umbrella for a real type that runs inside it
         * basically all this does in "run()" the QDoType;
         */
        public const bool DELETE_MODE = true;

        QDoType iam;

        public QDo(QDoType action)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            iam = action;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            iam.action();

            if (iam.callback != null) iam.callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't say that it is not FIFO. It says your multiples *tasks* print the result in different order (It may happen that tasks take the values in FIFO order but another task get scheduled before printing)

Comment: thanks @EZI yes, I thought so too so I added a 100ms sleep to check for that..

Comment: The `BlockingCollection` class by default uses a `ConcurrentQueue` as it's backing store which is obviously a FIFO structure. I'd recommend including code relevant to this issue into the question rather than via a link which could disappear at some point in the future and render this question redundant.

Comment: actually I can confirm that the `sleep` is behaving not as intended either :-/ I set it to 5000 ms and it isn't sleeping the worker objects at all it is sleeping (once) per Queue.. very odd

Comment: @MrHeelis *Sleep* doesn't change what I've said.

Comment: @EZI I'm not sure what you mean, it should make a queue of 6 jobs that all take 100ms and print (it doesn't but it seems this is another weakness :-s).. but were it too, surely that shows that it isn't a system.print issue? they are clearly happening in parallel not in serial, serial is FIFO parallel isn't FIFO at all (because it isn't a list at all)

Comment: @MrHeelis When you run n threads/tasks, you can never be sure in which order they would run or run to completetion at once. Since your taks print the result, the order of output is completely *unpredictable*

Comment: @EZI I don't think you've understood my question but thank you for looking :-) you *can* Queue events in a thread in sequence, that is what a FIFO Queue is :-)

Comment: You're creating a new consumer thread for every action that you enqueue. If you do that, then there's no point to even having a `BlockingCollection`. Normally you'd create one or more consumers--no more than the number of CPU cores you have available, and let them process items.

Comment: @JimMischel you wrote this after I posted a fix. May I ask: Why? Since the queue object is static I would have argued it `shouldn't` have spun up a new queue each time. I think the fact remains it span up a queue for every call. But describing `the effect`, is not the same as discussing `the cause` and (more immediately) `the solution`

Comment: It doesn't spin up a new queue each time; just a new thread. I posted that comment to help you understand that your technique is not the usual way of creating a producer-consumer application, and not the best use of `BlockingCollection`. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847905/threading-and-asynchronous-operations-in-c-sharp/ for a simple example of how to use `BlockingCollection` in a similar scenario. Or do a Web search for producer-consumer apps in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I was nearly there it was merely making sure that the consumer started before the producer (i.e. in the constructor), still not 100% sure *why* this works (but it definitely does! I assure you 100%!) it is tested on single unit runs too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QTest
{
    class nofQDo
    {
        static BlockingCollection<QDo> queue = new BlockingCollection<QDo>(new ConcurrentQueue<QDo>()); //<--new ConcurrentQueue<QDo>() makes it FIFO

        static nofQDo()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (QDo doThis in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    doThis.run();
                }
            });
        }

        public static void addAction(QDoType action)
        {
            QDo me = new QDo(action);
            queue.Add(me);
        }
    }
}
```

so now

```
QDoType_test gra = new QDoType_test("hey0"); nofQDo.addAction(gra);

QDoType_test grb = new QDoType_test("hey1"); nofQDo.addAction(grb);

QDoType_test grc = new QDoType_test("hey2"); nofQDo.addAction(grc);

QDoType_test grd = new QDoType_test("hey3");  nofQDo.addAction(grd);

QDoType_test gre = new QDoType_test("hey4");  nofQDo.addAction(gre);

QDoType_test grf = new QDoType_test("hey5");  nofQDo.addAction(grf);
```

produces

```
00009::hey0
00009::hey1
00009::hey2
00009::hey3
00009::hey4
00009::hey5
```

Comment: I just got 2 minus mark downs for no reason can an admin rectify please?